# For loop to create column based on unique dates in other column

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I am trying to get better at using loops and if statements. I know that the problem can be solved with other means, but it would be great if someone could help me figure it out this way.

I want to create a column in my data frame that "counts" each unique day of a date column. So if the day is "05" the column is 1, if it is "06" it is 2, if "07" it is 3, and so on. I attempt to solve this with if statements and a for loop.

My idea is to create a column "loop" with only zeros, an empty variable "date" and a "count" variable which is set to zero. I then go through the day column of my dataframe with a for loop, if the current row equals "date" then the loop starts again at the next row. If it does not equal "date" then the value of the row is assigned to date, +1 is added to "count" and the current value of "count" is assigned to my "loop" column at the current position of the loop. Then the loop starts again. It looks like this, but it only produces an error ("Error in 1:nrow(df$b) : argument of length 0"):

```
a <- rnorm(10)
b <- seq(as.Date("2022/05/05"), by = "day", length.out = 10)
df <- data.frame(a,b)
df <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), each = 2), ]

df$loop <- 0
date <- as.Date(x = integer(0), origin = "1970-01-01")
count <- 0

for (x in 1:nrow(df$b)){
  if(date==x){
    next
  }else{
    date <- x
    count <- +1
    df$loop[x] <- count}
  }
```

Comment: And what is the error?  That would be helpful to know.  `=` is an assignment operator `==` is the boolean equality operator.  So `if(date=x)` is probably wrong.  Whilst your desire to learn is admirable, personally I would suggest other areas of study would be more beneficial.  In R, a good rule of thumb is "if you're thinking of using a `for` loop, there's probably a better way to do it".

Comment: As Limey pointed out, in R there's often more suitable tools for iteration stuff than loops. Why? See this talk on cupcakes and loops by Hadley Wickham (https://hadley.nz/): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyNqlOjhPCQ